# Rails approval system

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using: Rails 4.0.1

I'm trying to create something like approval system for creating Events. 
I got something like 'User can create Place','User cn create Event','Event contain Place title as location'.

I made simple Place detector(what place was created by current user and show only this places)

```
events_controller.rb
def new
  @event = Event.new
  @places = current_user.place.all
end

in events form i got such field:
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :place_id %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:place_id, @places, :id, :title) %>
</div>
```

Of course i can show all places, but when i chose it, I don't know... maybe it shouldn't publish news and leave an approvement message for a place_author? Any ideas how to make it?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: i'm asking a suggestion how to logicaly make it